# How to mount OSX EFI partition with HFSprogs

Tags: dual-boot, mount, uefi, hfs+

I can mount my HFS drive without a problem, but mounting the EFI gives wrong filesystem type error, which is probably right, since it is an EFI system.

```
Device      Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1      40    409639    409600  200M EFI System
/dev/sdb2  409640 390459783 390050144  186G Apple HFS/HFS+
```

```
sudo mount -t hfsplus -o force,rw /dev/sdb1 /media/XXX/EFI
mount: /media/XXX/EFI: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

So how to mount an EFI system with HFS progs?

Comment: Please remove the `-t hfsplus` part and try again.

Comment: no luck: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

Comment: gparted shows the EFI partition is fat32 so:  sudo blkid ; 
    sudo mkdir /media/EFI  ;
    sudo mount /dev/sdc1 /media/EFI